# Can not remove my activity from the Stack

Tags: android

I know this has been asked. I browsed and tried whatever I have found but for some reason, it is not working for me.

my code is as follow

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
@Override
public void run() {
  Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, HomepageActivity.class);
  intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
  startActivity(intent);
}
```

I can not use

android:noHistory="true"

as my activity in some circumstances has to stay on the stack.

So, i have the following behaviour. I log in into my app with the LoginActivity, then it goes to the HomepageActivity, but if I press the Back bottom, the LoginActivity pops back again, which I do not want.

Any idea how I could fix this.

Answer (score 3):

This can be done by calling [`finish()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#finish%28%29) right after `startActivity()`.

`finish()` destroys the current Activity and therefore removes it from the Stack.

Answer (score 1):

Call `finish()` right before `startActivity()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can override `onBackPressed` method of your activity to do what you want